Remote Deskop "Access is Denied" but only if the user is not already logged in locally
I am using RDP to connect to a Windows 11 Pro 23H2 from a windows 10 machine.  If I am already logged on locally to the Windows 11 box, RDP works normally, kicking off the local user and letting the remote user in.
If the user account is not already logged in (first login after boot or after a timeout)  RDP just says "Access is Denied" with no info.  Event viewer shows a successful login.
I have tried everything I can find online with no luck.  I can't get any log to show anything being wrong, it's just RDP can't seem to activation the session unless it had already been logged in.
Same behavior with Domain accounts and local...user is Administrator and a member of the Remote Desktop Users group.
Any ideas?

This isn't a programming question, try [su].
